# rtsp client dont answer to server

Tags: java, sockets, rtsp

I'm writing a RTSP server. When I wait for header from client my server receives:

```
OPTIONS rtsp://192.168.1.147:55555 RTSP/1.0
CSeq: 2
User-Agent: LibVLC/2.0.1 (LIVE555 Streaming Media v2011.12.23)
```

readLine() in this place returns null.
 then I'm sending :

```
bw.write("RTSP/1.0 200 OK" + CRLF);
bw.write("Supported: play.basic, con.persistent");
bw.write("CSeq: " + RTSPSeqNb + CRLF);
bw.write("Session: " + RTSP_ID + CRLF);
bw.write("Public: SETUP, PLAY, TEARDOWN" + CRLF+CRLF);
bw.flush();
```

Where CRLF = "\r\n"
But there is no any response. My question: WHY?

Answer (score 0):

Did you forget to append `CRLF` to the second line before `CSeq`? Then lots of networking "why" questions could be answered with [wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org).

Comment: I've copied it but i remove this line from code but it there is still the same problem. Anyone can help?